# Reliably Detect .NET Framework Availability/Version from Browser

Tags: .net, browser

I'm know why this is probably not possible, and I know of BrowserHawk and smallestdotnet.com, which both apparently rely on IE's user-agent, but I'll ask anyway because SO is the biggest brain trust around, and I'm in great need.

Is there any way, *from a browser*, to detect which, if any, .NET Framework is installed on a Windows client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if the browser specifically supplies it, as you're aware, in the user-agent string. The only browser to do this that I know of is Internet Explorer (and maybe some bots mimicking IE) and you can't rely upon it in any other instance.

Comment: Left this open for a few days in the desperate hope someone would have a solution for me. I knew it wasn't going to happen. :(